# CSS table styling - special format

Tags: css, html-table

I need a table styling like below, where the milestone label is displayed without any spacing with the table content itself wile on the right of it I have a couple of additional information displayed in cells with spacing between them and below content.

divs can work as well.
[image]

Comment: Please post the code you have tried !

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Do you have HTML/CSS to provide as example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the cells at the top right as seperate tables with `position: absolute` and make the cell under those (the top right of the large table, spanning several columns)  invisible as shown below.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

th {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.head1 {
  background: #aaa;
  border-color: green;
}

.nohead {
  display: none;
}

table.t1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table.t2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 10px;
}

.t2 td {
  padding: 2px 15px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table class="t1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="head1">The main header</td>
    <td colspan="4" class="nohead">nothing to see</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Cell 1</th>
    <th>Cell 2</th>
    <th>Cell 3</th>
    <th>Cell 4</th>
    <th>Cell 5</th>
    <th>Cell 6</th>
    <th>Cell 7</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
    <td>Cell 5</td>
    <td>Cell 6</td>
    <td>Cell 7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="t2">
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B1</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```